# Multirow and multicolumn with columns fixed length

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn, multirow

I'm trying to draw a tabular in which the column lenghts are fixed. The problems occur when I use multirow and multicolumn, as the text is very long. This is my (not working) code

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.40\linewidth}|p{0.10\linewidth}|p{0.40\linewidth}}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Utilizzare le reti e gli strumenti informatici nelle attività di studio, ricerca e approfondimento}
    CRITERI/EVIDENZE    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{LIVELLI DI PADRONANZA} \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{Capacità di produrre un testo in forma multimediale, in forma di video o di presentazione}      &   
        A & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con  autonomia ed efficacia \\
        B & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con  una certa autonomia \\
        C & Si orienta nell’utilizzare diverse tecniche informatiche \\
        D & Utilizza lentamente gli strumenti informatici e su indicazione dell’insegnante.
\end{tabular}
```

and this is what I want to create

[image]

Comment: Your problem is the use of `*` for the width of the `\multirow`, as it means to use the 'natural width' of the text, which is large for a large text. As you can see in the answers given, `=` should be used instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a correct code. I added the possibility to have a table that uses the whole text width with `tabularx`. Note that the first argument in `\multirow` is not the number of *rows*, but the number of *lines*, to take into account the case of adjacent multiline cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.40\linewidth}|l|p{0.40\linewidth}|}
\hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{0.9\linewidth}|}{Utilizzare le reti e gli strumenti informatici nelle attività di studio, ricerca e approfondimento}\\ \hline
    CRITERI/EVIDENZE & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LIVELLI DI PADRONANZA} \\
    \hline
    \multirow{11}{=}{Capacità di produrre un testo in forma multimediale, in forma di video o di presentazione}
        & A & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con autonomia ed efficacia \\
     & B & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con una certa autonomia \\
     & C & Si orienta nell’utilizzare diverse tecniche informatiche \\ & D & Utilizza lentamente gli strumenti informatici e su indicazione dell’insegnante. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vskip 2em

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|l|X|}
\hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{\centering Utilizzare le reti e gli strumenti informatici nelle attività di studio, ricerca e approfondimento}\\ \hline
    CRITERI/EVIDENZE & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LIVELLI DI PADRONANZA} \\
    \hline
    \multirow{10}{=}{Capacità di produrre un testo in forma multimediale, in forma di video o di presentazione}
        & A & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con autonomia ed efficacia \\
     & B & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con una certa autonomia \\
     & C & Si orienta nell’utilizzare diverse tecniche informatiche \\ & D & Utilizza lentamente gli strumenti informatici e su indicazione dell’insegnante. \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Two another questions:
- what to do in order to resize the lenght of the first column "CRITERI/EVIDENZE" using tabularx option?
- what to do in order to center the text "CRITERI/EVIDENZE"?

Comment: @tomino: For  the first point, you can change the *ratio* of the widths of the two `X` columns, using the syntax `>{\hsize= x1\hsize}X` and similarly for the second  `X` column, with the condition that `x1 + x2 = 2` (more generally, the sum of the coefficients must be equal to the total `X` columns). To centre the first  column head, the simplest would be to add `\centering` before `CRITERI/EVIDENZE’.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|c|X|}
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{Utilizzare le reti e gli strumenti informatici nelle attività di studio, ricerca e approfondimento}    \\
    \hline
    CRITERI/EVIDENZE    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LIVELLI DI PADRONANZA} \\
    \hline
\multirow{11}{=}{Capacità di produrre un testo in forma multimediale, in forma di video o di presentazione}      
&       A & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con  autonomia ed efficacia \\
&       B & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con  una certa autonomia \\
&       C & Si orienta nell’utilizzare diverse tecniche informatiche \\
&       D & Utilizza lentamente gli strumenti informatici e su indicazione dell’insegnante.\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

**Addendum:**
For exercise, solution with use of new table package `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec={X c X},
                 hspan=minimal,
                 }
\SetCell[c=3]{c, yellow!30}    
        Utilizzare le reti e gli strumenti informatici nelle attività di studio,
        ricerca e approfondimento                                                           \\
CRITERI/EVIDENZE
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{h}    LIVELLI DI PADRONANZA                                            \\
\SetCell[r=4, c=1]{c}   Capacità di produrre un testo in forma multimediale, 
                        in forma di video o di presentazione
    & A & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con  autonomia ed efficacia    \\
    & B & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con  una certa autonomia       \\
    & C & Si orienta nell’utilizzare diverse tecniche informatiche                          \\
    & D & Utilizza lentamente gli strumenti informatici e su indicazione dell’insegnante.   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to set `\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth\relax` with `tabularray`, just use option`hspan=minimal`.

Comment: L.J.R., thank you very much. I looking for in package documentation how to define multi-column width, but didn't find any example for this :-(. Now I check gain and found description for it. Answer is corrected now:-).

Comment: Thanks! A question for the tabularx example: how to do if I want to create a hline only under "D | Utilizza lentamente..." ? I would like to expand this table with another gropu of ABCD levels but with the same first column.

Comment: @tomino, new problem, new question ;-). I do not understand what is your problem.  To write more table rows? Just add them. Change horizontal lines (`\cline{...}` instead of `\hline` or vice versa)?.  Do on the similar way as are already done. Please clarify!

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabularX}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.0 of 2021-08-10).

In that environment similar to the classical `{tabularx}` of the eponymous package, you have a command `\Block` to merge cells both horizontally and vertically.

For the vertical block, you specify the number of *rows* (and not the number of physical lines). However, for the horizontal block, you have to put a parbox with the correct width previously computed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{|X|c|X|}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
\hline
\Block[fill=yellow!15]{1-3}{\parbox{\mylength}{Utilizzare le reti e gli strumenti informatici nelle attività di studio, ricerca e approfondimento}}    \\
\hline
CRITERI/EVIDENZE    & \Block{1-2}{LIVELLI DI PADRONANZA} \\
\hline
\Block[l]{4-1}{Capacità di produrre un testo in forma multimediale, in forma di video o di presentazione}      
& A & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con  autonomia ed efficacia \\
& B & Utilizza diverse tecniche informatiche e strumenti con  una certa autonomia \\
& C & Si orienta nell’utilizzare diverse tecniche informatiche \\
& D & Utilizza lentamente gli strumenti informatici e su indicazione dell’insegnante.\\
\hline
\end{NiceTabularX}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]